# Is SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation() still valid in tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, siteedit

In Tridion 5.3 SP1 version we use SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation(objCP) to display editable component presentation on page. 
This is working fine in Tridion 5.3 SP1. We are migrating to Tridion 2011 SP1 so wanted to confirm that this function still exists in Tridion 2011 SP1 or its deprecated?

If its deprecated then let us know the alternate function for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading from SDL Tridion R5.3 to SDL Tridion 2011 is not a step to take lightly but it is a supported path. The first thing you should focus on is the changes in product prerequisites on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. SiteEdit is also still supported (even on VBScript templates) but for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 its is a complete newer version of the product named [User interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_EDC411EF58BD4700A8B6BD996AB102F3) (login required see [here](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion) for details). Since you are coming from SiteEdit 1.3, you should contact Customer Support about getting the SiteEdit Script Extension DLL for the upgrade from SiteEdit 1.3, since the documentation only mentions it from SiteEdit 2009 SP3.

The upgrade process itself is described in our [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/topic_0CA8B8211FC54ED0BC3FBFD65C439206) (login required see [here](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion) for details). Robert Curlette also wrote a nice [Blog article](http://www.curlette.com/?p=720) about the upgrade to SDL Tridion 2011.

The most important things to understand here is the big step you are going forward, from your example code I see you are still using VBScript templates, which are still supported in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, but they are deprecated so you should be looking into replacing them with our new template models. However SDL Tridion does not recommend you to include this in the upgrade project, because this would make the project too big and possibly unmanageable.

Probably the best advice I can give you for such an upgrade is to contact SDL Tridion Professional Services and have them do an upgrade scan, which will point out all the pain-points of this upgrade. Then they can also advice you the best way forward as depending on the details of your implementation, the details of the upgrade process might be different as well (like should you stay on VBScript templates or does it make sense to upgrade them, what to do with your event system and your extensions or customizations etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bart.. I have read the document link posted by you.. But still my question remains unanswered..whether SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation() is still valid in tridion 2011 SP1.I did not find it anywhere in the documents.

Comment: Please read my answer again, I mentioned SiteEdit is still supported on VBScript templates, which means that SiteEdit.ComponentPresentation() is still valid. You will need to contact Customer Support about getting the SiteEdit Script Extension DLL for the upgrade from SiteEdit 1.3 though.